# QUERY and UNIQUE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Given a table like this one:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TIE |
| 1 | TIE |
| 1 | TIE |
| 2 | WIN |
| 3 | TIE |
| 3 | TIE |
| 4 | LOSS |
| 4 | LOSS |

I need a query that returns in a different sheet

| A |
| --- |
| TIE |
| WIN |
| TIE |
| LOSS |

The actual sheet is here: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mYeatu2azaUxtg4HsxFu5N04Uc_AD63dE25HV1MOfJ8/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Couldn't you just use `=UNIQUE(A1:B8)`?

Comment: Just edited. Forgot to say that I need this result in a different sheet

Comment: So put the formula in the different sheet and reference the original in the range specified to `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Edited again... What I need is a result in a single column in another sheet

Comment: Successful? Or not working at all...?

Comment: not working yet...